# Prove that $G-F$ is Hamiltonian for a specific graph $G(V,E), F \subset E$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G(V,E)$ be a simple graph with $|V|=n$ and $\delta(G) = \delta$. For any $u,v \in G$ with $uv \not \in E$, we have $\deg u +\deg v \geq n$, and $F \subset E$ with $|F| \leq \left\lfloor{\frac{\delta-2}{2}}\right\rfloor$. Prove that $G-F$ is Hamiltonian.

I have already proved that $G-F$ is connected. Then, consider a longest path in $G-F$, say $P$ = $v_1v_2\ldots v_p$. If I can find any $v_i, v_j \in P$ with $|i-j| \geq 2$ such that $v_iv_j \in E(G-F)$, then I can find a suitbale cycle in $P$, and claim that cycle is Hamitonian: If the cycle is not Hamitonian, then since $G-F$ is connected, there is a vertex in $G-F$ that is adjacent to a vertex in the cycle, this produce a longer path than $P$, a contradiction.

So my question is, how to find the cycle?

Comment: Did you mean that for any pair of non-adjacent vertices $u$ and $v$ it is true that $\deg u + \deg v \ge n$?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the post.